# Yocto Recipe Not Installing File to Image

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack

I have a recipe for installing a file to a directory on my image. The folder structure for the recipe is this:

```
recipes-foo
|___foo
    |___foo_0.1.bb
    |___files
        |___sources.list
```

The .bb file has the following content:

```
DESCRIPTION = "utils config file"
LICENSE = "MIT"

SRC_URI = "file://*"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/apt
    install -Dm 0755 ${S}/* ${D}{sysconfdif}/apt
}

FILE_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/apt/*"
```

After "several" iterations I still cannot get the file to be installed on the image. Is there another way to approach this? Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems that you maybe forgot to add your recipe to the layer conf. maybe you could test adding IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " foo" in the local.conf file. this will tell your image recipe to include your new package in the final image

Comment: 1) The `SRC_URI = "file://*"` line is invalid (you need to specify the file, not wildcard); 2) Is there any error?

Comment: @BadrElHiouel layer.conf? I have the meta-myfolder layer folder added to the bblayers.conf

Comment: The bblayers.conf file tells BitBake what layers you want considered during the build. The variable IMAGE_INSTALL_append in conf/layer.conf lists out the base set of packages to install from the Package Feeds area. https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-IMAGE_INSTALL

Comment: @BadrElHiouel thanks. After rereading the information here, I will go back and try again and repost later.

Comment: @BadrElHiouel I added the packages to the local.conf but now I get errors about license files. Do I need license files for my own custom files to be installed?

Comment: Try adding LICENSE = "CLOSED" in your recipe. for more information about licences : https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-LICENSE.

Comment: You can't include two recipes in a single that installs the same file in the same path. I don't use dep packages with yocto, but is /etc/apt/sources.list already populated? If so, you should probably want to use /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ folder.

Comment: There is a type on the name **sysconfdif**. It should be **sysconfdir**, doesn't it?